# I uploaded an image with web2py, now it opens for download instead view in browser. Why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, http-headers, web2py

Using web2py and Google App Engine, I create on a model file, a field to upload the image and another one to save its download URL.

```
Field('logotipo_marca_url', 'upload', uploadfield='logotipo_marca_blob'),
Field('logotipo_marca_blob', 'blob'),
```

I order to retrive the image save, I use the default download code from example application:

```
function download():
    return response.download(request,db)
```

When I use the image URL inside html IMG tag, the image is displayed within HTML... but if I paste the image on browser, it will be downloaded instead open in browser.

I've tried to change the response headers, like "Content-type" and "Content-Disposition" but I had sucess with it.

Q1:
I need that image opens inside the browser.

Q2: And one thing else happens, the image is downloaded with the same original file name it were uploaded... I need change it and a name that I will choose. How can I do that?

Comment: Go to GAE admin -> Blob Viewer, and check the `Content Type` of your blobs. What content type is it?

Comment: I'm using the Datastore, so there are no blobs listed in Blob Viewer... Is that right? But when I go to Datastore Viewer, I see: logotipo_marca_blob
    value: 66769 bytes, SHA-1 = fe833540f8569270958fb97a38c8bb24ff806a22 
    type: blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image must have `Content-Type=image/jpeg` (or other relevant type: png, gif..) in order for browser to treat it like an image.  Do not use [`Content-Disposition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition), this is in browsers used to declare data as downloadable file.

Comment: Hi Peter! I already tryied change Content-Type... like this...    

def download():
    import gluon.contenttype    
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = gluon.contenttype.contenttype('.jpg')   

    return response.download(request,db)


but... no success... Am I doint it wrong?

Comment: Should I change it on models\databse? How?

Answer (score 1):

ftfy

```
function download():
    return response.download(request,db, attachment=False)
```